# How is floating point conversion actually done in C++?(double to float or float to double)

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, type-conversion

So I've searched about this topic and found nothing really relevant about it.

I've tried to look at the assembly behind this simple code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double d = 1.0;
    float f = static_cast<float>(d);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

which is (with Visual Studio 2012) :

```
    15:     double d = 1.0;
000000013FD7C16D  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [__real@3ff0000000000000 (013FD91AB0h)]  
000000013FD7C175  movsd       mmword ptr [d],xmm0  
    16:     float f = static_cast<float>(d);
000000013FD7C17B  cvtsd2ss    xmm0,mmword ptr [d]  
000000013FD7C181  movss       dword ptr [f],xmm0
```

I'm not that comfortable with assembly but tried to analyze that anyway.
So the first two lines seems to move the double-precision value `3ff0000000000000` into a register, and then move the content of the register to the memory adress of d.

Then, I just don't know exactly what does the next lines. The `cvtsd2ss` operation is apparently an instruction that [convert double precision floating point value to single precision floating point value](http://www.asmpedia.org/index.php?title=CVTSD2SS) but I couldn't find what this instruction actually does. 
(Then the converted value is moved to the memory space of f).

So my question is, how is this conversion actually done by this instruction ? I know that the C++ cast will yield the closest value in the other type but apart from that, I have no idea about the actual operations performed...

Comment: "I know that the C++ cast will yield the closest value in the other type". What more do you need to know?

Comment: [Intel Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Volume 2.

Comment: You might want to read about it in the [Intel Architecture Reference](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf) (Warning: large PDF), especially starting on page 241.

Comment: Are you asking for the actual algorithm?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually it's more curiosity than practical knowledge. I don't know if it's quite wrong to post this kind of questions... @CarlNorum/JerryCoffin: Thanks for the reference, I didn't think of that kind of place to search for, should have...

Comment: I wasn't saying that it was wrong. I was trying to work out what you were asking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh I didn't mean that, I was just wondering.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `cvtsd2ss` instruction uses the FPU's rounding mode to do the conversion. The default rounding mode is round-to-nearest-even.

In order to follow the algorithm, it helps to keep in mind the information at the [IEEE 754-1985 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), especially the diagrams representing the layout.

First, the exponent of the target `float` is computed: the `double` type has a wider range than `float`, so the result may be `0.0f` (or a denormal) for a very small `double`, or an infinite value for a very large double.

For the usual case of a normal `double` being converted to a normal `float` (roughly, when the unbiased exponent of the `double` can be represented in the 8 bits of a single-precision representation), the first 23 bits of the destination significand start out the same as the most significant of the original number's 52-bit significand.

Then there is the problem of rounding:

- if the left-over bits are below `10..0`, then the target significand is left as-is.
- If the left-over bits are above `10..0`, then the target significand is incremented. If incrementing it makes it overflow (because it is already `1..1`), then the carry is propagated into the exponent bits. This produces the correct result because of the careful way the IEEE 754 layout has been designed.
- If the bits left over are exactly `10..0`, then the `double` is exactly midway between two `float`s. Of these two choices, the one with the last bit `0` (“even”) is chosen.

After this step, the target significand corresponds to the `float` nearest to the original `double`.

The directed rounding modes are only simpler. The case where the target `float` is a denormal is slightly more complicated (one must be careful to avoid “double-rounding”).

Comment: OK, but in the code in the question, a double is converted to a single

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, I will amend the answer.

Comment: Even the single-to-double conversion cannot just move the bits. Normal values require adding 896 to the exponent. Denormal values require finding the first bit set, shifting the significand, and adjusting the exponent.

Comment: @EricPostpischil All original denormal values convert to `0.0f` in a round-to-nearest double->float conversion. The case where the result is a denormal is not too different from the normal->normal case once left over bits are described with regexps such as “10..0”, and in any case, I do not intend to detail it more. Please feel free to write your own answer if you feel that it cannot be left out. When this answer refers to “exponent”, it is the “unbiased exponent” (or “biased exponent”, whichever is zero for the floating-point number 1.0).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: My comment is for the single-to-double conversion.

Comment: @PascalCuoq About "All original denormal values convert to 0.0f in a round-to-nearest double->float conversion". It's interesting, does it work this way even for denormal that are closer to the smallest possible floating-point representation than to zero ?

Comment: @JBL This answer focuses on the double->float conversion, because that is tricky enough as it is. Double denormals are found between -DBL_MIN and DBL_MIN (~2*10^-308). The smallest strictly positive float is ~1.401298e-45, so for this particular conversion, there is no chance that any denormal input number rounds to something other than 0 in round-to-nearest.