# Is primitive casting, creates a new object in memory?

Tags: c++, memory, casting

My question is simple, if I have the following code in C++:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i1 = 5;
    int i2 = 2;
    float f = i1/(float)i2;
    std::cout << f << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Is `(float)i2` going to create a new object in memory that is next going to devide `i1` and assigned on `f` or the **casting** operator is somehow translating `(float)i2` on the fly and do the devision with not extra memory for the casting?

Also, what is going on with cases that casting requires different sizes of variables? (e.g. from float to double)

Comment: For casting from float to double or the other way, you may find some useful information there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737615/how-is-actually-done-floating-point-conversion-double-to-float-or-float-to-doub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `(float)i2` going to create a new object in memory

The cast creates a temporary object, which will have its own storage. That's not necessarily in memory; a small arithmetic value like this is likely to be created and used in a register.

> Also, what is going on with cases that casting requires different sizes of variables?

Since a new object is created, it doesn't matter whether that they have a different size and representation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler implementation and machine architecture. The compiler can use CPU registers for temporary variables, and it can also use stack memory if needed. Studying the assembly level output of the compiler would tell you what it does in a particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the conversion can be stored in memory or in a register. That depends on your hardware and compiler and compilation options. Consider the result of compiling your snippet with `g++ -O0 -c -g cast_code.cpp` on a cygwin 64 bit gcc:

```
  [...]
  14:   c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0x4(%rbp)
    int i2 = 2;
  1b:   c7 45 f8 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
    float f = i1/(float)i2;
  22:   f3 0f 2a 45 fc          cvtsi2ssl -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0
  27:   f3 0f 2a 4d f8          cvtsi2ssl -0x8(%rbp),%xmm1
  2c:   f3 0f 5e c1             divss  %xmm1,%xmm0
  30:   f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)
  [...]
```

The ints are moved onto the stack, and then converted to floats which are stored in mmx registers. New objects? Debatable; in memory: rather not (depending on what is memory; to me memory should be addressable).

If we instruct the compiler to properly store the variables (e.g. in order to avoid precision issues with the more precise registers), we get the following:

`g++ -O0 -c -g -ffloat-store cast_code.cpp` results in

```
  // identical to above
  14:   c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0x4(%rbp)
    int i2 = 2;
  1b:   c7 45 f8 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
    float f = i1/(float)i2;
  // same conversion
  22:   f3 0f 2a 45 fc          cvtsi2ssl -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0

  // but then the result is stored on the stack.
  27:   f3 0f 11 45 f4          movss  %xmm0,-0xc(%rbp)

  // same for the second value (which undergoes an implicit conversion).
  2c:   f3 0f 2a 45 f8          cvtsi2ssl -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
  31:   f3 0f 11 45 f0          movss  %xmm0,-0x10(%rbp)
  36:   f3 0f 10 45 f4          movss  -0xc(%rbp),%xmm0
  3b:   f3 0f 5e 45 f0          divss  -0x10(%rbp),%xmm0
  40:   f3 0f 11 45 ec          movss  %xmm0,-0x14(%rbp)
```

It's somewhat painful to see how i1 is moved from the register to memory at 27 and then back into the register at 36 so that the division can be performed at 3b.

Anyway, hope that helps.