# What is the definition of Convert_Single_Precision_To_Double_Precision_Floating_Point() in the Intel software developer manuals?

Tags: floating-point, x86

In the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), the operation of the `CVTPS2PD` and `CVTSS2SD` instructions is described using a Convert_Single_Precision_To_Double_Precision_Floating_Point() pseudocode function.

What is the definition of this pseudocode function?

I searched the combined software developer manual (325462-056US), and the "Operation" sections for `CVTPS2PD` and `CVTSS2SD` are the only two places where this particular pseudocode function is mentioned.

**EDIT:** In particular, how are the corner cases where the single-precision floating point number represents SNaN, QNaN, or ±Infinity handled?

Comment: It is pseudo, just a placeholder.  Actual implementation is likely done in a custom logical circuit design tool that Intel developed in-house and most certainly will not share with anybody.  You'd need a pretty high-power microscope to look at the silicon result :)

Comment: There's nothing secret about converting single-precision to double-precision. Incidentally the procedure has already been described somewhere on StackOverflow

Comment: In the other direction (which is similar, only more difficult): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737615/how-is-actually-done-floating-point-conversion-double-to-float-or-float-to-doub

Comment: @PascalCuoq I probably should have mentioned in my question that I was interested in the corner cases.  There is currently an active [pull request to the .NET CoreFX project](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/4401) in which one of the questions is whether a `float` representing NaN or Infinity still represents NaN or Infinity when cast to a `double`.

Comment: updated my answer with my best guess about what happens.  It's easy enough to test on real hardware, if you're really paranoid.  Just use a debugger and run the instruction.  I think it's safe to assume every x86 CPU ever will give the same output for any given input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, every 32b float can be exactly represent by a 64b double, so there's no rounding or anything needed, making this function too trivial for Intel to bother documenting the details.

The actual details of how the bits are moved / transformed are moderately complicated.  I'm not going to try to summarize, but see njuffa's comment for a start.  The point is that there's a unique correct result for every 32b input, so you don't need to know how it's implemented.  The results will match every other correct implementation.

This isn't the only place in the Intel insn ref manuals where they use a function without defining it, if the name is long and descriptive enough that they don't need to.

---

Re: **+/-Inf and NaN**: I can't think of any good reason why +/-Inf would map to anything other than +/-Inf.

[NaN has many unused bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), so IDK how those are transformed.  I'd assume that NaN maps to NaN, but the only question is what happens to the "payload".  I'd assume SNaN -> SNaN, and QNaN -> QNaN.

Mapping those floats to any specific number would make no sense at all.  You could imagine mapping `float` +Inf to the next `double` after `FLT_MAX`, but that seems like a terrible idea and I'd be shocked if anyone's ever implemented the conversion that way.

Comment: "Zero-padding" may not be the right term when talking about the exponent manipulation needed. Since in IEEE-754 floating-point formats, the exponent field is biased, the conversion from `binary32` to `binary64` involves re-biasing the exponent. Might be advantageous to clarify the answer in this regard.

Comment: @njuffa: thanks, I'm not an FP expert.  I knew it probably wasn't going to be as simple as just zero padding, but anyway thanks for catching my mis-statement.